# Allow auto import my React library on vscode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to do a library of components for React and publish on npm using webpack and babel to compile to Es5.

Almost everything worked, but for some reason, the project that consumes this lib cant auto import their components

I have a project on github with the setup I used:

https://github.com/dattebayorob/react-loading

```
//webpack.config.js
https://github.com/dattebayorob/react-loading/blob/master/webpack.config.js
```

```
//.babelrc
https://github.com/dattebayorob/react-loading/blob/master/.babelrc
```

```
//package.json
https://github.com/dattebayorob/react-loading/blob/master/package.json
```

I'm expecting to import components from my lib with 'CTRL+space' when typing then

Now, I can import from my lib manualy with `import { Component } from 'my-react-lib'`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, when using Typescript in VSCode, you have to run the `Typescript: Restart TS Server` command in your command palette for auto import to work after creating new files. It's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

On `dattebayorob/react-loading/index.d.ts` try:

```
export  *  from './src/components'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `package.json`, you have `"main": "./index.d.ts"`, but that's not a valid JS file, as it does not contain actual code, only type definitions.

In a library, usually you need to have an `src/index.js` file that imports / exports all components and in `package.json` you add the build artifact as main: `"main": "dist/index.js"`.

Also, don't forget to explicitly specify the `files: ["dist"]` attribute in `package.json` so the src folder is not downloaded when your package is installed.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem as the OP. Even if I put `dist/index.js` and generate that `dist/index.js` during build (I use Rollup instead of Webpack), I am not able to navigate to the library code when I import components from another project. Could you share some resources or useful tutorials that can teach everything someone needs to know when building JS libraries published to NPM? Thank you!